# AOSP building fails due to undefined references

Tags: android, c++, g++, android-source

I've downloaded the Android 2.3.6 source code and I've successfully built it.  Then, I added a C++ library into the external folder and I tried to build it but, when I did, I received the following errors:

```
prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-eabi/bin/ld: path/to/myfile.cpp:26: error: undefined reference to '__cxa_end_cleanup'
prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-eabi/bin/ld: : error: undefined reference to '__gxx_personality_v0'
in function path/to/myfile.cpp:26: error: undefined reference to 'operator delete(void*)'
```

I added this line to the Android.mk file:LOCAL_CXX=path/to/g++compiler
in order to use g++ compiler 
but it still use .../arm-eabi/bin/ld to link with other libraries how can i force the use of g++ as a linker.

Comment: I remember there is no file named myfile.cpp in Android. So can you provide the source of myfile.app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compile & link C++ code with `g++` and not `gcc`.

Comment: i used make CC=gcc-4.4 CXX=g++-4.4 -j4
but i still got the same errors

Answer (score 0):

Had errors of the same kind, along with `'out/xxx/yyy.o: file is empty'`. For me the reason was that VM crashed during the build process, leaving some files corrupted (didn't have to do `repo sync`, corrupted files were binaries).

I removed directory containing the problematic files, restarted the build process and the errors were gone.